# Is there a Microsoft DataVisualization Chart that can show coloured Weight Loss progress

Tags: c#, data-visualization

I am using the latest Microsoft Data Visualization library (3.5) to produce certain charts for showing the progress for a persons' weight loss over a period of time. What I am trying to show is a chart that shows their loss (or gain) using a range chart. This is actually fairly easy to do using this library, but I am not sure how I am able to produce a chart like the following:

[image]

The issue that I have is trying to get the red spikes showing when there is a weight gain. When I apply a color to a particular series point, the colour is from that point until the next point. Not in the middle.

So, pictures speak a thousand words, how am I able to produce an output similar to the chart shown above?

Thanks,
SR

Comment: Use three data series.  One for red, one for green and one for the moving average.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that is a good idea. The moment I posted this question and looked at the graph example again, I came to this conclusion when I noticed that the red and green slightly overlap each other. I would probably need to floor the data series at 0 to the positive and negatives accordingly, but that is straight forward enough